# How to swap fields on docs with unique constraint in MongoDB/mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unique

I have docs in series:

```
[{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    position: 1,
    name: 'This doc'
},
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    position: 2
    name: 'That doc'
}]
```

`position` field has a unique constraint. Also, I need them all ordered, from 1 to `n` with no holes.

How can I swap those things? If I put pos:1 to pos:2 and the other way around, I try to save, I get validation error on the first doc. Or when I try to save the whole series, it's even harder (ie. move doc from pos 7 to pos 2, which in turn moves all from 2-6 down by one).

What is a good strategy to do this with MongoDB? And, preferably applicable to Mongoose models or schemas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap all the *other* fields than `position`.

```
var query = {$or:[{position: 1},{position: 2}]};
Schema.find(query, function(err, docs){
    Object.keys(docs[0]).forEach(function(key){
        if(key=='position') return;
        var temp = docs[0][key];
        docs[0][key] = docs[1][key];
        docs[1][key] = temp;
    });
    docs[0].save();
    docs[1].save();
});
```

Comment: Awesome idea, thanks :) Going to be a bit of work but it solves the problem.

Comment: Good one. Does the suggested code work even if the two documents have different number of fields?

Comment: @Prem It's iterating over the properties of `docs[0]`, so if some properties exist in `doc[1]` they might be left out. Maybe you could store those properties names in an array and re-iterate over `doc[1]` and do the same thing but omitting those array values cuz they're already done. .. or something like that.

Comment: Yes.The same scenario required at my end and i have done with that what you have suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue with swapping docs in an array. I found a great solution using the Mongoose array "set" function. Here is a link to the Mongoose documentation:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.set

For example, docs saved in the db:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a7f57258bf04b578c6ce0c"),
    "name" : "playlist_1",
    "songs" : [
        {
            "artist" : "Brand New",
            "album" : "The Devil and God",
            "title" : "Archers",
            "album_pic" : "29.mp3",
            "song" : "0.jpg",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57a7f62d58bf04b578c6ce0d")
        },
        {
            "artist" : "Modest Mouse",
            "album" : "Lonesome Crowded",
            "title" : "Cowboy Dan",
            "album_pic" : "31.mp3",
            "song" : "30.jpg",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57a7f63c58bf04b578c6ce0e")
        },
        {
            "artist" : "Portugal. The Man",
            "album" : "The Satanic Satanist",
            "title" : "People Say",
            "album_pic" : "33.mp3",
            "song" : "32.jpg",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57a7f65758bf04b578c6ce0f")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 3
}
```

Here is the function for swapping the array items in "songs":

```
function swapSongs (songIndex1, songIndex2) {
    var playlistName = 'playlist_1',
        swap1,
        swap2;

    //Model called playlist
    Playlist.findOne({name: playlistName}, function (err, playlist) {
        swap1 = playlist.songs[songIndex1];
        swap2 = playlist.songs[songIndex2];
        playlist.songs.set(songIndex1, swap2); //.set(index, newThing)
        playlist.songs.set(songIndex2, swap1);
        playlist.save();
    });
}
```

Here is the result of `swapSongs(0,2);`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a7f57258bf04b578c6ce0c"),
    "name" : "playlist_1",
    "songs" : [
        {
            "artist" : "Portugal. The Man",
            "album" : "The Satanic Satanist",
            "title" : "People Say",
            "album_pic" : "33.mp3",
            "song" : "32.jpg",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57a7f65758bf04b578c6ce0f")
        },
        {
            "artist" : "Modest Mouse",
            "album" : "Lonesome Crowded",
            "title" : "Cowboy Dan",
            "album_pic" : "31.mp3",
            "song" : "30.jpg",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57a7f63c58bf04b578c6ce0e")
        },
        {
            "artist" : "Brand New",
            "album" : "The Devil and God",
            "title" : "Archers",
            "album_pic" : "29.mp3",
            "song" : "0.jpg",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57a7f62d58bf04b578c6ce0d")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 3
}
```

Hope that helps!